# Como usar métodos de otra clase ( de otro archivo ) en un archivo js distinto

Tags: javascript, poo

Antes de nada disculparme si el título no es muy descriptivo, pero no consigo explicarme mejor..

Para poneros en situación estoy haciendo un juego tipo RPG pero en modo de texto.

Primeramente he hecho una clase llamada personaje, que está en un archivo. Este es el código

```
function personaje(n){

// Atributos

var nombre      = n;            // Nombre
var oro         = 500;          // Oro
var exp         = [0,1000,1.1]; // exp actual / exp base lvl 1 // multiplicador por nivel
var ultMision   = 4;            // Ultima misión realizada
var stats       = {
    nivel:      19,             // Nivel del personaje y aumenta vida por cada nivel.       inicial = 1
    fuerza:     75,             // Con la fuerza sacaremos el daño mínimo y náximo..        inicial = 5
    destreza:   25,             // Aumenta la probabilidad de crítico, y el daño máximo.    inicial = 5
    vitalidad:  20,             // Aumenta la vida maxima.                                  inicial = 5
    dureza:     33,             // Reducimos el daño recibido.                              inicial = 5
    danio:      {
        minimo: Math.ceil(stats.fuerza / 2),
        maximo: danio.minimo + (Math.ceil(stats.destreza / 2))
    },
    prbCritic:  Math.ceil(stats.destreza / 10),
    vida:       Math.ceil(100 + ((stats.vitalidad * 3) + (stats.nivel * 10))),
    reducDanio: Math.ceil(1 + (stats.dureza / 5))
};

// Métodos

// Golpea y daña una cantidad dependiendo si es critico o no
this.golpear = function(){
    var danioGolpeo = this.numAle(stats.danio.maximo, stats.danio.minimo);
    if(this.esCritico()){
        return danioGolpeo * 3;
    } else {
        return danioGolpeo;
    }
};

// Dice si es golpe crítico o no
this.esCritico = function() {
    return this.numAle(100,1) <= stats.prbCritic;
};

this.subeNivel = function(){
    this.setNivel(this.getNivel() + 1);
};

// Genera número aleatorio entre dos números
this.numAle = function(max,min){
    return Math.round(Math.random()* (max - min ) + min);
};

// Suma una cantidad al oro existente
this.sumaOro = function(cantidad) {
    this.setOro(this.getOro() + cantidad);
};

// Resta una cantidad al oro existente
this.restaOro = function(cantidad){
    this.setOro(this.getOro() - cantidad);
};

// Para saber si la misión ya está completa
this.isCompletaMision = function(num){
    return num <= ultMision;
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaFuerza = function(cantidad){
    this.setFuerza(this.getFuerza() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaFuerza = function(cantidad){
    this.setFuerza(this.getFuerza() - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaDestreza = function(cantidad){
    this.setDestreza(this.getDestreza() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaDestreza = function(cantidad){
    this.setDestreza(this.getDestreza() - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaVitalidad = function(cantidad){
    this.setVitalidad(this.getVitalidad() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaVitalidad = function(cantidad){
    this.setVitalidad(this.getVitalidad() - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaDureza = function(cantidad){
    this.setDureza(this.getDureza() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaDureza = function(cantidad){
    this.setDureza(this.getDureza() - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaReducDanio = function(cantidad){
    this.setReductDanio(this.getReductDanio() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaReducDanio = function(cantidad){
    this.setReductDanio(this.getReductDanio() - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaDanioMinimo = function(cantidad){
    this.setDanioMinimo(this.getDanioMinimo() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaDanioMinimo = function(cantidad){
    this.setDanioMinimo(this.getDanioMinimo() - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaDanioMaximo = function(cantidad){
    this.setDanioMaximo(this.getDanioMaximo() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaDanioMaximo = function(cantidad){
    this.setDanioMaximo(this.getDanioMaximo() - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaVida = function(cantidad){
    this.setVida(this.getVida + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaVida = function(cantidad){
    this.setVida(this.getVida - cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.sumaExo = function(cantidad){
    this.setExp(this.getExp() + cantidad);
};

// para sumar una cantidad al stat
this.restaExp = function(cantidad){
    this.setExp(this.getExp() - cantidad);
};

// Getters y setters

this.getNombre = function(){
    return nombre;
};

this.setNombre = function(n){
    nombre = n;
};

this.getNivel = function(){
    return stats.nivel;
};

this.setNivel = function(n){
  stats.nivel =  n;
};

this.getOro = function(){
    return oro;
};

this.setOro = function(c){
    oro = c;
};

this.getExp = function(){
    return exp;
};

this.setExp = function(e){
    exp = e;
};

this.getFuerza = function(){
    return stats.fuerza;
};

this.setFuerza = function(f){
    stats.fuerza = f;
};

this.getDestreza = function(){
    return stats.destreza;
};

this.setDestreza = function(d){
    stats.destreza = d;
};

this.getVitalidad = function(){
    return stats.vitalidad;
};

this.setVitalidad = function(v){
    stats.vitaldad = v;
};

this.getDureza = function(){
    return stats.dureza;
};

this.setDureza = function(d){
    stats.dureza = d;
};

this.getReductDanio = function(){
    return stats.reducDanio;
};

this.setReductDanio = function(rd){
    stats.reducDanio = rd;
};

this.getDanioMinimo = function(){
    return stats.danio.minimo;
};

this.setDanioMinimo = function(dm){
    stats.danio.minimo = dm;
};

this.getDanioMaximo = function(){
    return stats.danio.maximo;
};

this.setDanioMaximo = function(dm){
    stats.danio.maximo = dm;
};

this.getVida = function(){
    return stats.vida;
};

this.setVida = function(v){
    stats.vida = v;
};

}
```

Ahora estoy realizando en otra clase llamada item, también en otro archivo distinto. Este es el código

```
function item(){

var lvl = this.setlvlItem();


this.setlvlItem = function(){
    var num = this.numAle(100,1);
    if(num <= 3){
        this.setLvl("Legendario");
    }
    else if(num <= 10){
        this.setLvl("Raro");
    }
    else if(num <= 30){
        this.setLvl("Magico");
    }
    else if(num <= 60){
        this.setLvl("Mejorado");
    }
    else {
        this.setLvl("Normal");
    }

};

this.numAle = function(max,min){
  return Math.round(Math.random()*(max - min) + min);
};

// getters y setters

this.setLvl = function(l){
    lvl = l;
}

}
```

Aquí es donde vienen mis dudas: Estando en el archivo item.js. ¿ Cómo puedo hacer referencias a métodos de la clase personaje ? y que estos me vayan apareciendo en el IDE ( Use WebStorm )

Si estuviera el objeto instanciado se que irían apareciendo, pues ya sabría de que clase es el objeto y aparecerían sus métodos en el IDE. Pero por ejemplo a la hora de programarlo en la clase item, tengo que hacer referencía a objetos sin estancar todavía y a sus métodos

Por ejemplo ahora quiero añadir en la clase item unos métodos que están en la clase personaje, y/o aumentarán o cambiarán atributos de la clase personaje

No se si me he explicado bien. Un saludo y gracias chicos

Comment: Primero decir que esta no es la mejor forma de simular programacion orientada a objetos en javascript, te recomeindo que le eches un vistazo a los prototipos https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp, aunque no te ayude en la respuesta espero que te ayude a aprender mas de javascript, otra cosa, me parece que debes annadir el tag webstorm a tu pregunta, y quizas quieras indagar sobre transpilar el codigo con babel o algun otro.

Comment: Le echaré un ojo. Hasta ahora había programado así en js  my me funcionaba.

Answer (score 2):

**Estoy asumiendo que estás desarrollando en ES6**

---

Para poder exportar e importar funciones de archivos, tienes que realizar algo así:

```
export function esCritico(){
    return this.numAle(100,1) <= stats.prbCritic;
} // No sé si podrías hacerlo de la manera que tienes en tu código, osea declarando variable
// E inmediatamente asignarle el valor de la función, puedes probar.
```

Y para importarlo en tu item.js:

```
import {esCritico} from 'personaje'

var perejil = esCritico() // Deberia regresar el valor del return
```

No estoy seguro que WebStorm pueda intuir el contexto como lo quieres, aunque siempre se puede esperar de JetBrains, son fantásticos!

*Enserio lo siento si no funciona alguna parte, en especial la del `import`, pero es que en éste momento no puedo comprobarlo, déjame saber si te sirve o no y luego le podré dar una mirada ;)*

**Fuente:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

**EDICIÓN:** Por como dijo @Daniel Pérez, quizá sea necesario ocupar un compilador de terceros para que éste código sea viable en browsers más viejos y con menor soporte en general, algo como [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Sin embargo, ***siempre debes colocar tus archivos más pertinentes e importantes en una misma carpeta, o como mínimo, en carpetas muy cercanas, a la ves que especificar el directorio EXPLÍCITAMENTE***.

Aparte de eso, todo debería funcionar perfectamente :D.

Comment: Este codigo no funciona en los browsers, quizas debas explicar o referenciar a como compilar los ficheros para unirlos o poder usarlos en el cliente como con babel, webpacks u otros

Comment: De hecho podría servir, pero en el import tendrías que especificar la ruta explícita del archivo .js, ahí donde va el nombre del archivo; la verdad es de experimentar. Creo que sí no sirviera con los browsers, no tendría razón de ser, pero honestamente no lo he ocupado antes, hago todas las funciones locales :P

Comment: Tienes razon, esta en el estandar de javascript, pero es relativamente nuevo asi que muchos browsers no lo van a soportar, por lo que es practica comun transpilar el codigo